# Shaping the input for LSTM model using Keras Python

Tags: python, keras, time-series, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

We are working with a kaggle dataset : https://www.kaggle.com/heesoo37/120-years-of-olympic-history-athletes-and-results/version/2. It has the data of 120 years of olympics.
Our aim is to train our model on the previous olympics' data and to predict the likely medal of country in the next olympics based on the trained model. We are taking the attributes : age, sex, height, weight, NOC(country), sport, event to predict our output class(gold,silver,bronze no_medal). We wish to use LSTM to make prediction based on few previous years' data rather than whole dataset of 120 years.

But the main challenge in using LSTM we are facing is that how to shape the input to the LSTM. What should be the time-step and sample size for LSTM?
How should the data be grouped for feeding it to the LSTM. For each country we have variable number of rows corresponding to each year of olympic and all combination of sports.

We are stuck on this step for a couple of days.

It would be great if someone can please give insights on how the input should look to be fed to LSTM.

We have written code like this:

def lstm_classifier(final_data):

```
country_count = len(final_data['NOC'].unique())
year_count = len(final_data['Year'].unique())

values = final_data.values
final_X = values[:, :-1]
final_Y = values[:, -1] 
print(country_count, ' ', year_count)

# reshape - # countries, time series, # attributes
#final_X = final_X.reshape(country_count, year_count, final_X.shape[1])
final_X = final_X.groupby("Country", as_index=True)['Year', 'Sex', 'Age', 'Height', 'Weight', 'NOC', 'Host_Country', 'Sport'].apply(lambda x: x.values.tolist())
final_Y = final_Y.groupby("Country", as_index=True)['Medal' ].apply(lambda x: x.values.tolist())

# define model - 10 hidden nodes
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(10, input_shape = (country_count, final_X.shape[1])))
model.add(Dense(4, activation = 'sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error', metrics = ['accuracy'])

# fit network
history = model.fit(final_X, final_Y, epochs = 10, batch_size = 50)

loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(final_X, final_Y)
print(accuracy)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am in the same situation. I want to make a User level prediction from raw log data.
Actually, I don't know the right solution, but I have picked up some tricks.

I think you are in a good way. First, you have to transform  2D data into 3D, as Jason Brownlee do Click [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/convert-time-series-supervised-learning-problem-python/)!

An another good example Click [here](https://github.com/Azure/lstms_for_predictive_maintenance/blob/master/Deep%20Learning%20Basics%20for%20Predictive%20Maintenance.ipynb)!

They use this methode:

Keras LSTM layers expect an input in the shape of a numpy array of 3 dimensions (samples, time steps, features) where samples is the number of training sequences, time steps is the look back window or sequence length and features is the number of features of each sequence at each time step.

```
# function to reshape features into (samples, time steps, features) 
def gen_sequence(id_df, seq_length, seq_cols):
    """ Only sequences that meet the window-length are considered, no padding is used. This means for testing
    we need to drop those which are below the window-length. An alternative would be to pad sequences so that
    we can use shorter ones """
    data_array = id_df[seq_cols].values
    num_elements = data_array.shape[0]
    for start, stop in zip(range(0, num_elements-seq_length), range(seq_length, num_elements)):
        yield data_array[start:stop, :]
```

If you have found better solution, please don't hesitate, and share with us :-)